# How can I deploy elasticsearch to kubernete?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kubernetes

I installed `minikube` on my Mac and I'd like to deploy elasticsearch on this k8s cluster. I followed this instruction: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-deploy-elasticsearch.html

The file I created is:

```
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: quickstart
spec:
  version: 7.10.0
  nodeSets:
  - name: default
    count: 1
    config:
      node.store.allow_mmap: false
```

when I run `kubectl apply -f es.yaml`, I got this error: `error: unable to recognize "es.yaml": no matches for kind "Elasticsearch" in version "elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1"`

It says `kind` is not matched. I wonder how I can make it work. I searched k8s doc and it seems `kind` can be `service`, `pod`, `deployment`. But why the above instruction uses `Elasticsearch` as the `kind`? What value of `kind` should I specify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might have missed the step of installing CRD and the operator for ElasticSearch. Have you followed this step https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-deploy-eck.html?

`Service`, `Pod`, `Deployment` etc are Kubernetes native resources. Kubernetes provides a way to write custom resources also, using [CRDs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/). `Elasticsearch` is one such example, so you have to define custom resource before using it for Kubernetes to understand that.